# Banach space "over $\mathbb Q$"

Tags: banach-spaces

> My question: can we define Banach space over the field $\mathbb Q$
> instead of over the usual $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$? Will $\mathbb R$
> be a Banach space over $\mathbb Q$ if it can be done?

The reason why I am asking this is because I have read that every separable Banach space does not have Schauder basis.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the field choice by Q replacing R/C"?

Comment: So whenever I see the defination of Banach space it's always on a field, and it's mostly either R or C(Real or Complex) if I want the field to be Q(rational) will i still be able to define Banach space?

Comment: And if I do that will R be a banach space over the field Q or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with doing analysis over $\mathbb{Q}$, is that $\mathbb{Q}$ lacks the *completeness* property: **not every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ converges.** 
This makes it pretty much impossible to do analysis over $\mathbb{Q}$, after all "natural" theorems become false: For instance it’s possible to have a monotonic bounded sequence which does not converge, or have a bounded set with no LUB, or have a continuous function which fails IVT, etc.

Comment: For the sake of completion (especially meant to the OP of the question), there is no non-trivial norm on $\mathbb Q$ such that $\mathbb Q$ is a complete normed vector space over itself. In case he/she or others wonders we should introduce a different norm on the rationals.

Answer (score 3):

Banach spaces, by definition, are **normed** vector spaces.

And by definition, **normed** vector spaces are spaces over $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space)). Therefore, you cannot define a Banach space over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: The natural follow up question is "What goes wrong with a normed space over $\mathbb{Q}$?"

Comment: @Korf $\mathbb{Q}$ lacks completeness. eg in $\mathbb{Q}^2$ with an "orthonormal" basis $(e_1, e_2)$ the vector with coordinates $(1, 1)$  is expected to have norm $\sqrt{2}$ but $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$...